# Pyspark Joining dataframes with multiple rows in the second dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join a dataframe "df_1" with "df_2" on a column named "TrackID".

```
 df_1:   cluster    TrackID
           1           a_1
           2           a_1
           3           a_2
           1           a_3

 df_2:   TrackID     Value
           a_1         5
           a_1         6
           a_2         7
           a_2         8
           a_3         9
Output:   
         cluster    TrackID   Value
          1           a_1    Vector(5,6)
          2           a_1    Vector(5,6)
          3           a_2    Vector(7,8)
          1           a_3    Vetor(9)
```

I want the output of the join to look like this. is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Did you mean `vector(7,8)` for `a_2` and `vector(9)` for `a_3`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with *ArrayType*, you can aggregate the second data frame by *TrackID* first and then join with the first data frame:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_2.groupBy('TrackID').agg(
    F.collect_list('Value').alias('Value')
).join(df_1, ['TrackID']).show()

+-------+------+-------+
|TrackID| Value|cluster|
+-------+------+-------+
|    a_1|[5, 6]|      1|
|    a_1|[5, 6]|      2|
|    a_2|[7, 8]|      3|
|    a_3|   [9]|      1|
+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will wait if someone can give me a solution for the vector output.

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding a `udf` to convert the collected list to vector in @Psidom's answer

```
#importing necessary libraries
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, collect_list, col
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT

#udf for changing the collected list to vector
@udf(VectorUDT())
def vectorUdf(x):
    return Vectors.dense(x)

#grouping and aggregation for collecting values and calling the above udf function
vectorDf_2 = df_2.groupBy('TrackID').agg(vectorUdf(collect_list('Value')).alias('Value'))

#joining the two dataframes
Output = df_1.join(vectorDf_2, ['TrackID'])
```

which should give you

```
+-------+-------+---------+
|TrackID|cluster|Value    |
+-------+-------+---------+
|a_1    |1      |[5.0,6.0]|
|a_1    |2      |[5.0,6.0]|
|a_2    |3      |[7.0,8.0]|
|a_3    |1      |[9.0]    |
+-------+-------+---------+

root
 |-- TrackID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cluster: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Value: vector (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful